# While-Loop not exiting when reading command

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, console, command

I have a problem when using while-loops to read the text a command returns. 
I have the following code:

```
class CommandExecuter {
  ProcessBuilder builder = null;
  Process p = null;
  BufferedWriter writer = null;
  String str = "";
  BufferedReader hey = null;
  StringBuffer buffer = null;

  CommandExecuter() {
  }

  public void run() {
    builder = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash");

    try {
      p = builder.start();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
    hey = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    buffer = new StringBuffer();
  }

  String exec(String command) {
    try {
      writer.write(command);
      writer.newLine();
      writer.flush();
      int a = 0;

      while ((str = hey.readLine()) != null) {
        a++;
        System.out.println(a);
        buffer = buffer.append(str + ":");
      }

      System.out.println("finished");
      return buffer.toString();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "1";
  }
}
```

The problem is, the while loop is doesn't when the console finished printing text. It never reaches the part where it prints "finished". When using the command ls, it return a 8 lines long String. The variable "a" prints till it reaches 8, and stops, but the loop does not exit because it never reaches the finished part.

Comment: I updated the question to include the full code

Comment: And what is `/bin/bash`?

Comment: It is used to start a new Bash session to execute commands on it (I am using Mac OS X btw)

Comment: Does it ever close its standard output or does the process ever end?

Comment: Yes, it does exit, but it never exits the while loop, although it stops printing

Comment: There should be ; after a++ in the loop.

Comment: Thanks, I changed that now, but it still doesn't work

Comment: I may be misunderstanding what you are trying to do, but I think you have the input and output streams reversed.  The output of your child process (bash) should be your input, and vice versa.

Comment: No, all is working fine, only the while-loop-execution doesn't end. It prints all the command returns.

Answer (score 0):

You are running an interactive shell and feeding it commands through standard input; once a command is executed, the shell will print its output and keep running, waiting for more commands. Therefore, standard output of the shell process will never be closed.

What you should probably do instead is run each command as its own, new, process, possibly as `/bin/bash -c command`.